# Higher efficiency when reading large files in R

Tags: r, large-files

I provide this imaginary problem to see how R-experts handle the (multiple) large data  problem.

Suppose you have *3* big files (*10 G*), each *3* columns, **datetime**, **number** and **redundant**. The objective is to read files, if **datetime** matches (this means rows are not matched by row numbers, suppose there is only slight difference) and if sum of numbers is *K*, keep them. This is what I do:

```
Row<-1000000
Temp1<-data.frame(datetime=character(),
                 number1=numeric(),
                 number2=numeric(),
                 number3=numeric())

for(i in 0:100){
    File1<-read.table("File1",skip=i*Row+1, ,nrows=Row, na.string="NULL",
                      ColClasses="character","numeric","NULL"),header=TRUE))

    File2<-read.table("File2",skip=i*Row+1, ,nrows=Row, na.string="NULL",
                      ColClasses="character","numeric","NULL"),header=TRUE))


    File3<-read.table("File3",skip=i*Row+1, ,nrows=Row, na.string="NULL",
                      ColClasses="character","numeric","NULL"),header=TRUE))


   result<-Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="datetime"),list(File1,File2,File3)))

   Temp2<-result[(result$number1+result$number2+result$number3)==k,]
   Temp1<-rbind(Temp1,Temp2)
}
```

How would you handle this specific problem? How do you usually handle this kind of problems?

What should I be careful about when handling large data? In my experience cbind is very slow.

What tools are very helpful here?

Comment: `data.table` package, `?fread`

Comment: @Ben: I use it often, but not good when you have `nrow=...`

Comment: are you on a system where you can use `head` and `tail` from the system (i.e., Unix or a Windows box with cygwin)?

Comment: Not now, I searched for it. How could it help?